# Missing script/generate in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-generate

I just installed Rails 3 and created my first app.  The install of Rails3 + ruby 1.9 went very smoothly but I am missing the generate script in script/generate.

I have created a new app from scratch with no options to verify.

Any idea why this is happening and how to fix it?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

all `script/*` commands has been removed from rails 3. You should use `rails generate` or `rails g` instead of `script/generate`, `rails server` or `rails s` instead of `script/server` and so on.

Answer (score 3):

try

```
rails generate ...
```

the only script existing now is `rails` all others will be called as parameter of rails.

Take a look a the Ruby on [Rails Guides: Getting Started with Rails](http://guides.rails.info/getting_started.html)