# Why does Ruby "script/generate" return "No such file or directory"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, scriptgenerate

I am having trouble using `script/generate`. I am following the [tree based navigation](http://railscasts.com/episodes/162-tree-based-navigation) tutorial, which says to use `script/plugin install git://github.com/rails/acts_as_tree.git` or `script/generate nifty_layout`.

I keep getting:

> No such file or directory -- script/plugin

I've tried these variations:

```
script/generate nifty_layout
rails generate nifty_layout
ruby script/generate nifty_layout
ruby generate nifty_layout
```

and they all tell me:

> -bash: script/generate: No such file or directory

Am I missing something? Total ruby nuby here and I just can't seem to find an answer.

**edit**: rails 3 on Mac OS X 10.6

Comment: Sorry, rails 3 on Mac OS X 10.6

Comment: Are you in the correct directory?

Comment: Also, are other script/generate commands working properly?

Comment: Most probably, you created a new project, `rails new foo_proj` and then forgot to `cd foo_proj`.

Comment: Yes, in the correct directory. No other script/generate works.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Rails 3 is your problem (or rather the cause of).  Since rails 3 all of the "script/whatever" commands have been replaced with "rails whatever".

So now you want "rails generate ..." or "rails server" instead.

Be sure to watch version numbers or post dates when looking at tutorials :)
linkage:
[Missing script/generate in Rails 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3024478/missing-script-generate-in-rails-3)

Comment: I gave that answer as well, but when I read the full question, I realized that jyoseph had tried that.

Comment: Thanks. I'm scared to add up the hours that I've spent tracking down "oh, it used to be that way but now it is this other way" while learning Rails. Backward compatibility is bad somehow?

Answer (score 2):

There is a LOT of out-of-date information on the interwebs for Rails now as a result of it evolving quickly and being so popular. I use the [Ruby on Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/) as my first stop for information as those pages seem to be the most current.

The [`rails generate`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/command_line.html#rails-generate) info seems current.

Answer (score 1):

you may try a couple things, first, make sure since you are using rails 3 that you have run 'bundle install'. depending on how you installed rails and which version of bundler you are using, it may not be finding your rails binary to execute the `rails generate ..` so you may try prefixing it with `bundle exec rails g` but that is deprecated and you should get a warning if you call it. Also, make sure you are following ryan's instructions for rails 3 (and run bundle install once you add to the gemfile) on his library: https://github.com/ryanb/nifty-generators

Answer (score 0):

As a shortcut to rails server, you can use 'rails s'. Similarly for the console, 'rails c'.