# Error: No such file or directory, when trying to execute [ruby script/generate]?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am writing a small blog application using Rails. I am using Aptana Studio.

When I try to execute:

```
ruby script/generate scaffold post title:string body:text
```

from either Aptana Studio or going to the project folder and executing it from the shell, I get this error:

```
c:\Ruby200\bin\ruby.exe: No such file or directory -- script/generate (LoadError
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are meaning to do `rails generate`?

First create a new Rails app:

```
rails new random_app
cd random_app
rails generate scaffold post title:string body:text
```

When you "ruby" something, it looks for a file to execute.

Rails is the framework for abstraction and scaffolding.

See "[Why does Ruby "script/generate" return "No such file or directory"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4320759/why-does-ruby-script-generate-return-no-such-file-or-directory)".

Rails 3 is the problem. Since Rails 3, all of the "script/whatever" commands have been replaced with "rails whatever".

So now you want `rails generate ...` or `rails server` instead.

Comment: The blog I am referring to is using ruby script/generate. http://sixrevisions.com/web-development/how-to-create-a-blog-from-scratch-using-ruby-on-rails/

Comment: that blog is outdated, ruby script/generate has been replaced with rails commands. see the link the above answer

Comment: Ok. Thanks. Can you suggest any new link which illustrates how to create a blog using Rails?

Comment: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/ 
this is the best site. they have a blog tutorial similar to the one that you were looking at, http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html

Comment: Thanks a lot James. It helped much.