# Raise an error on Ruby/Script generate scaffold

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Hi guys i am currently still learning Ruby. Anyway i am on chapter 13 on web application development.I am stuck at this part for ruby script/generate Entry tittle:string content:text

Based on my research i have came across this link:
[Why does Ruby "script/generate" return "No such file or directory"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4320759/why-does-ruby-script-generate-return-no-such-file-or-directory)

Apparently i used Rails 3. so this is what happened.I located to my directory i run this command
D:\RubyProjects/Part-3/Chapter-13/rails/mydiary> rails generate scaffold Entry title:string content:text

Now i got this error:
Bundler could not find compatible version for gem "bundler
Current Bundler version: 1.13.2
This Gemfile requires a different version of Bundler.

And i also tried to run this as well:
install bundle,
gem install bundle

Can anyone help me on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to install bundler.

```
gem install bundler
```

and than

```
bundle install
```

after this you can generate scaffold

also look [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9854225/bundler-could-not-find-compatible-versions-for-gem-bundler)

Comment: After i issue this command bundle install i get the following message. Could not locate Gemfile or .bundle/ directory. But after i change the directory where my rails project belong i issue the command and i get back the same error that i created the topic

Comment: I tried the link you gave.still doesn't work at all.

Comment: @Suresh you need to create gemset and then install bundle to solve this type of problem.

Comment: @Satosh Sharma What does gemset got to do with this?

Comment: @Suresh Ok let me look into this.

Comment: Does anyone face the same issue as well?

Comment: @Satosh Sharma still looking in to it?

Comment: @Suresh i have looking on stack overflow and other solution and i found same solution  as given above.

Comment: Hais i need to continue my chapter. But stuck with this error. Haha @Santosh Sharma

Comment: i have solved it already. basically what i did was editing the gemfile under rails to 4.0.0. then gem install bundler and bundle install and then you delete mydiary project and create a new projects and then you issue that command. :)

Answer (score 0):

I tried another command like this:
bundler exec rails g Entry Title:String content:text

Error appeared like this:
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "bundler":
  In Gemfile:
    rails (= 3.0.1) x64-mingw32 was resolved to 3.0.1, which depends on
      bundler (~> 1.0.0) x64-mingw32

Current Bundler version:
    bundler (1.13.2)
This Gemfile requires a different version of Bundler.
Perhaps you need to update Bundler by running `gem install bundler`?

### Could not find gem 'bundler (~> 1.0.0) x64-mingw32', which is required by gem 'rails (= 3.0.1) x64-mingw32', in any of the sources.

I tried to uninstall bundler version 1.13.2
and install bundler version 1.0.0. The same thing appear again.
How do i set the default version for bundler?