# Ruby Error: "No such file or directory -- script/generate (LoadError)"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I know that this error has been discussed elsewhere on the web, and this may seem like a stupid question, but I've got a very strange situation on my hands here.

I'm running on Snow Leopard, with fully updated Ruby and Rails gems. I created a new Rails project using `ruby new testing`, then navigated into that folder using `cd ~/testing`, and tried to create a basic scaffolding using `ruby script/generate scaffold newtest name:string`, and I got this error back:

> ruby: No such file or directory -- script/generate (LoadError)

I have searched Google thoroughly and tried to implement every solution that I could, but nothing has been working. I don't understand why I have this error or how to fix it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you are on rails 3 then the command is:

```
rails generate scaffold newtest name:string
```

Or the slightly shorter:

```
rails g scaffold newtest name:string
```

Notice **rails** not **ruby**.

Comment: Thank you. I feel so dumb haha

Answer (score 2):

If you're on Rails 3, you need to use the `rails` command instead, which now does much of the scripting.

(This is according to [another StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3024478/missing-script-generate-in-rails-3).)

Comment: Great call. I feel like an idiot. The correct total command is: rails generate scaffold [NAME] [FIELDS]

Comment: Don't worry about it. I'm still on Rails 2 myself, so I know I'm going to be in for a bumpy ride if I ever try Rails 3. (That said, currently I'm trying Django. *apologetic smile*)

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the latest version of rails then you no longer use script/generate.

In Rails 3 try using something like this instead:

```
cd ~/testing
rails generate scaffold Post name:string title:string content:text
```

You can find more info on the difference between rails 2 and rails 3 here if you like:

http://www.viget.com/extend/rails-3-generators-scaffolding/